# How to mock a s3 object in python?

Tags: python-3.x, python-unittest, python-unittest.mock

In my code there is a method which get csv files from s3 bucket. i need to mock that object in my test file. Below is the source function

```
s3 = boto3.client('s3')
def method():
    ...
    obj = s3.get_object(bucket, key)
    csv_content = obj['Body'].read().decode('utf-8')
    ...
```

I need to mock above 'obj'. Do i need to use separate modules? please suggest your thoughts

Answer (score 0):

Moto is the common package used in python to mock S3 and some other AWS services.

https://github.com/spulec/moto